# Is a pull request visible to the public?

Tags: github, version-control, open-source

I forked someone's repo yesterday, it was an old one and have been trying to port their code from Python 2 to Python 3. I cloned it locally, worked on it, then pushed the changes to GitHub. It is almost functional and have been looking at the pull request feature on GitHub which I've never used before:

[image: pull request]

I noticed as I was exploring the forks that GitHub nicely displays on a timeline who forked the original repository when and the commits they have done to it. It is kind of helpful that that is also open-source as I noticed that someone else was also trying to build the same compatibility as me.

So what I want to know is, once that 'pull request' button is pushed, does that just send a private message to the owner of the original repo telling them to have a look at the changes and possibly merge it in, or is it also visible to the public, available for comment etc? Am just trying to understand how the open source process works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it is visible to everyone.

- Purpose ?
- Code Review !

Others can review your changes, and comment on particular snippets

Comment: Thanks, that basically answers it - it was a yes/no question..  So that is another insight into how open source works. The thing that is good here is also, that if the owner of the repository ignores your pull request and it was technically without problems, then the community can observe that interaction and comment on it.